# Excel: Formula for calculating items belonging to a category in a given period

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

I need to sum the amounts (column A) belonging to a particular project (defined as Text in Column B) in the given period (date in Column C).

[[image: Let's say that's the example:]

What I need is to be able to have a calculation in another sheet of the sum of all items belonging to each Project in each month.

What I tried so far is the `SUMIFS` function, with this formula:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A,'Sheet 1'!B:B,"*Project 1*",'Sheet 1'!B:B,"*/02/*")
```

but the condition with the date is clearly not the way it's supposed to be - as it turns 0 value.

Comment: what did you try so far? SO isn't a 'solve instead of me', it's about asking specific questions and help.

Comment: It's a good point indeed. I edited now the original thread giving the direction I've been trying.

Comment: Without you providing sufficient information, I would guess that a Pivot Table would be ideal for this purpose.

Comment: Debug your formula. Try first just to SUMIF amount in Column A by Project. Then try to SUMIF amount in Column A by Date (*does* `"*/02/*"` *really works????*) Once you got each individual, just combine them in 1 unique SUMIFS

Comment: It's not the cleanest fix, but you could easily create a new column using the `=MONTH()` function that identifies the month out of column C. Then have your SUMIFS compare against the new column to match month.

Comment: Pivot tables are probably the easiest method (as @RonRosenfeld has said) but if you want to use an `SUMIFS` consider that you need `>=` the start of the month, and `<` the start of the next month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplistic solution, but it works. 
I still invite you to share your more elegant solutions.

To deal with the issue of the date, create extra columns for the period (I needed both month and year)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSzn9.png)

The formula then is (taking all the Project 1 items for March 2018): =SUMIFS(A1:A3, B1:B3, "Project 1", D1:D3, 3, E1:E3, 2018)

Answer (score 0):

## SUMPRODUCT OPTION

Moving away from sumifs you could use SUMPRODUCT.  Sumproduct uses array like calculations and as such you should avoid using full column references within the function or you will generate an excessive number of calculations. In this case your formula will look something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3*(B1:B3="Project 1")*(Month(C1:C3)=2)
```

When excel does evaluted the logical check of for B1:B3="Project 1" it will generate an array of True and False.  As long as those true and false values are sent through a math operator, they will be converted to 1 and 0 respectively.  So for your small case you will get something like the following

```
 100 * True  * True
 200 * False * True
-500 * True  * False
```

Which will convert to

```
 100 * 1 * 1
 200 * 0 * 1
-500 * 1 * 0
```

Which will convert to

```
100
  0
  0
```

The last step sumproduct performs is a summation of the values in the list.  As such in your case your total will be 100.

Of interest, in the above sumproduct formula above, the * acts as the equivalent of AND.

## SUMIFS

If you wish to stay with SUMIFS, you could use the following which would allow for full column references if needed:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A,'Sheet 1'!B:B,"Project 1",'Sheet 1'!B:B,"<=28/02/18",'Sheet 1'!B:B,">=01/02/18")
```

EDIT:

Alternate method of entering date range end points

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet 1'!A:A,'Sheet 1'!B:B,"Project 1",'Sheet 1'!B:B,"<="&DATE(18,2,28),'Sheet 1'!B:B,">="&DATE(18,2,1))
```

Date function is

```
=DATE(year,month,day)
```

where year, month and day are all integers.

[image: POC]

Comment: The array with the date does not seem to be working.
I tested the formula on the exact example I posted here and the result it returns is 0. Is ...*MONTH(C2:C4)=2) a correct expression?

Comment: I've been trying several approaches, even without the dates - just with another text value - so the error seems to be the adding the second condition. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: assuming your date in in C2 use the following fomula:  `=ISTEXT(C2)`  The results of this will tell us if the date is an excel date or simply text.  If it is text it will need to be converted to a date to use with the formula. or the formula will need to be adjusted to look for the month in the date.

Comment: Also be sure you have adjusted all your ranges.  I see the original question was using C1:C3.  If you have added a header row and bumped down the range to C2:C4, adjust the other ranges so they are of equal length.  Technically they can be offset as long as their length match, but usually its easier to track if they all line us in the same row.